# Getting log4net's XML configuration file read in ASP.NET webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, log4net

I'm trying to get log4net working in a 'classic' webforms app, using a log4net XML configuration file that I know is correct, as it is a copy of a file I use successfully with a number of other applications. I have the `config.log4net` file in the main site folder (`C:\inetpub\wwwroot\`), and I configure log4net in `Global.asax.cs` as follows:

```
protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var log = LogManager.GetLogger("SomeWebsite");
    XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo("config.log4net"));

    // bind log to the DI container
    ...
}
```

Whenever I then use the `log` instance (even within `Application_Start`) nothing happens, not even an error. I know that if `config.log4net` is misconfigured, log4net will silently fail, but I am sure that this isn't the problem. I have a feeling it has to do with `FileInfo`'s base path being wrong.

What is the best way to configure log4net in this situation?

Comment: Try to turn on log4net internal debugging. "To enable log4net's internal debug programmatically you need to set the log4net.Util.LogLog.InternalDebugging  property to true."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Server.MapPath if you are going to grab the file that way:

```
var fi = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/log4net.config"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Add your Log4Net Configuration in the web.config like this:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
</configSections>

<log4net debug="true">
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="C:\\TestProj\\TestLog.txt" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Size" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
        <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

Comment: Thanks @sajoshi, that looks like the _right_ way to configure log4net, but I wanted to keep the separate file as it is used in a number of other applications as well. +1 still